# Preorder Tree Traversal Algorithm to VB structure

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have been researching about this MPTT and I found this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/) however there are points that I cannot understand and I need the guru's here to help me about the schematics

```
FOOD
  FRUIT
   RED
    CHERRY
   YELLOW
    BANANA
  MEAT
   BEEF
   PORK
```

above is the example of a tree provided on the article

```
+--------+-------+------+-----+
| parent | title | lft  | rgt |
+--------+-------+------+-----+
|        | FOOD  |   1  |  18 |
|  FOOD  | FRUIT |   2  |  11 |
|  FRUIT | RED   |   3  |  6  |
|  RED   |CHERRY |   4  |  5  |
|  FRUIT |YELLOW |   7  |  10 |
|  YELLOW|BANANA |   8  |  9  |
|  FOOD  |MEAT   |   12 |  17 |
|  MEAT  |BEEF   |   13 |  14 |
|  MEAT  |PORK   |   15 |  16 |
+--------+-------+------+-----+
```

above is the example of the table based on the article

Questions:

1. I will copy the table structure mentioned above on my current project. What do you think? is there any room for improvement?
2. How do I obtain the values on LFT and RGT and saved to the table?

BTW: I am using vb.net(vb in particular) and MYSQL as my database

Thank you and have a nice day!

Regards

Anvy

Comment: The article provides how to get the values using PHP. Why can't you first try to get the logic of the PHP code, and write the vb equivalent?

Comment: It is very vague and there are some points on PHP structure that I don't understand.

Comment: Then be the guru to sort out the algorithm that is implemented and provide a similar implementation in vb.net. As you say, it is so vague, so probably no one would want to go through that pain to provide a solution.